# ModuleNotFoundError, i am trying to install pandas but i got some error

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, command-prompt

i am trying to install Pandas(or any other libraries) by running "pip install library-name" command in my command prompt(or also in window power shell) but i got some error(i attached screen shot for your reference,please see the screen shot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq1PF.png))i.e "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.vcs.git'" and i am not able to solve it out...please help me out on this

Comment: can you add the full stack trace of everything that happens after you `pip instal`?

Comment: sorry notacorn i didn't get you, please explain me little more

Comment: can you copy/paste into your question everything that happens after you type `pip install pandas`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reinstalling pip by following [this link](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/) or installing miniconda [here](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).

After installing miniconda, create a new environment (conda create --name NAME OF ENVIRONMENT python=3.6) and then activate it (conda activate NAME OF ENVIRONMENT).

Replace NAME OF ENVIRONMENT with your name of choice (2 environments can't have the same name). Anaconda is not needed for this, only miniconda.

Every time you make a new environment, a new pip is installed, ensuring that it will almost always work with ease.